# Vigenere Cipher syntax errors

Tags: python, vigenere

I am supposed to make a program that behaves likes this this:

```
$Python 
vigenere.py
Type a message:
The crow flies at midnight!
Encryption key:
boom
Uvs fsck rmwse bh auebwsih!
```

Using the Vigenere Cipher

I am to use a helper function and import it into this function, which I know works

```
import string

alphabet_pos = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
def alphabet_position(letter):

    pos = alphabet_pos.index(letter.lower())
    return pos 

def rotate(letter, rot):
    pos = alphabet_position(letter)
    new_pos = (pos + rot) % 26
    new_char = alphabet_pos[new_pos]

    return new_char
```

After that I began encrypting the Vigenere portion of it

```
from helpers import alphabet_position, rotate
from caesar import encrypt

    def encrypt(text,key):
        #Declare variable
        cipher = ''

        #Compute length
        l = len(key)

        #Assign value
        idx = 0

        #Loop
        for i in text:
            #if condition satisfies
            if i.isalpha():

                #Call method
                cipher += rotate_character(i,alphabet_position(key[idx]))

                #Update to next 
                idx = (idx+1)%1
            #Otherwise
            else:

                #Increment
                cipher += i

        #Return
        return cipher
    #Define main
    def main():
```

When I run this, it will ask me to type a message, but returns saying there are syntax errors in line 51, in `<module> main(`) and 
line 38, in

```
main text = input("Type a message: /n"))
File "<string>", line 1
```

Comment: You seem to have an extra `"` in the input

Comment: Syntax highlighting, like Stack Overflow uses here, can make these types of issues more obvious. It's probably a good idea to work in an editor that at least offers that feature (most do).

Comment: This may be because you’re using Python 2, where `input` gets the user’s input and tries to evaluate it as if it were Python code. If it isn’t, you will get a syntax error. You almost never want to use that function; use `raw_input` (or upgrade to Python 3, where that problem doesn’t exist).

Comment: As a side note, this code may fail if you type a letter that isn’t an ASCII letter, like `é` or `å`. In Python 2, you might get away with it. In Python 3, where all text is always Unicode, `isalpha` will be true for those letters, but their index into the list of ASCII letters isn’t very helpful. So, you might want an explicit check like `if i.lower() in alphabet_pos`, or maybe don’t check in advance and just write code in `rotate` that deals with `index` failing by just `return letter`.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why you used `main text = ...` INSTEAD of just `text = ...` or `main_text = ...` and also looks like you have an extra parenthesis at the end....

so,

if you want to get a string from the user and store it in a variable `text` you should rewrite your statement like this:

IF you are using **Python3**:

```
text = input("Type a message: ")
```

IF you are using **Python2**:

```
text = raw_input("Type a message: ")
```

Please specify what version of python you are using next time you ask so it's easier for us to answer :)

*(You can check the version you are running with `import sys; print(sys.version)`)*